# ASP.NET application with Oracle Database and Entity Framework 6 - Compatible Entity Framework database provider couldn't be found

Tags: asp.net, .net, oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm getting this error.
[image: Error]

> Your project references the latest version of Entity Framework; however, an Entity Framework database provider compatible with this version could not be found for your data connection. If you have already installed a compatible provider, ensure you have rebuilt your project before performing this action. Otherwise, exit this wizard, install a compatible provider, and rebuild your project before performing this action.

**Update:** The project multiple layers based on onion architecture. I have realised that I am able to add new model to other solutions / layers. However I'm not able to add this one which I keep most of my models.

**My system properties:**

- I'm running windows 10 x64 Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 x64
- Target    framework: .NET Framework 4.5.2
- Entity Framework 6.1.1
- Oracle.Managed Data Access Entity Framework 12.1.24
- Oracle.ManagedDataAccess 12.1.24160
- (ODT) Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2015
- ODAC 12.2c Release 1 64-bit (12.2.0.1.0)

**What I have tried**

1. I have modified entity framework string like this

```html
 <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.122.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
```

```html
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.OracleConnectionFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework">
</defaultConnectionFactory>
```

2. I have uninstall both ODT and ODAC and installed and installed previous release of them.
3. I ve downgraded Entity Framework from 6.1.3 to 6.0.
4. I have change project build option from "Any CPU" to "32 bit" and tried installed all the components accordingly in 32 bit. Didn't work.
5. I have checked or compared web config and app config files which contains any configuration about oracle and entity framework, but couldn't see anything wrong.

Comment: Oracle ODP.NET Managed Provider runs independently from 32 bit or 64 bit, it should work in either case. Check section `<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>` in your .NET Config file (`machine.config`, `web.config`, `user.config`)

Comment: I have app.config and web.config file. I checked them but could not see anything wrong. Can you be more specific please? I'm updating question to add some more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying all these, I recreated the solution which I used to keep model classes and now I am able to add model. Problem solved.

Comment: Yes I found solution and written it to here for the people who may experience the same problem. And yes I marked it as a solution cause it is a solution.It also remains unanswered in other case.But I couldn't really understand why it bothers you sir.

Comment: nothing bothers me, this is just like joke. Even I am not so good at joking, I like joke